# Using jquery how to call a function and call another function from the previous when function execution is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, function-call

I have to perform a task based on jquery. When the page loads, the first jquery function will be called. Once the first function completes successfully, then it should automatically call the next function.

Comment: Please show code as it is not clear what is your problem... There is nothing special need to be done to call several functions in a sequence.. Or whoever upvotes the post next please explain the problem better.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried so far....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working **demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/mvFnm/)**

JS:

```
function func_one()
{
    alert('func_one');           
    alert('Now call func_two');   
    func_two();
}

function func_two()
{
    alert('func_two');    
}
//jquery Function block that will be executed on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    //call the function one
    func_one();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is actually a function then just call it `functionA()` as per good ol' JavaScript.  If it is an event then use Jquery `trigger` see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

if it is possible then chaining the functions might also be a good idea.as in `FunctionA().FunctionB();`

Answer (score 0):

you can 'pass' callback function to other functions. see example:

```
function one(callback) {
    // do stuff ...
    // do stuff ...
    // do stuff ...

    if (typeof(callback) === 'function') 
        callback();
}

function two() {
}
```

now, declare document ready and call function `one`. when it completes, we'll call function `two`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    one(function(){
        // code after 'one' ended
        two();
    });
});
```

that's the general idea. hope that helps.